# Can I re-export a type from a different Python type stub file?

Tags: python, python-typing

I am writing type stubs for a proprietary Python platform. The platform often defines classes in some modules and re-export them from other modules. I need my type stubs to reflect that the type exists in more than one file.

For example

_foo.py:

```
class SomeType:
    # Implementation here
```

foo.py:

```
from _foo import SomeType
```

How do I write type stubs for these files?

I have tried this:

_foo.pyi:

```
class SomeType:
    ...
```

foo.pyi:

```
from _foo import SomeType
```

But it doesn't work, mypy throws this error:

> error: name 'foo.SomeType' is not defined

Is there a way to make this work without copy-pasting the type stub into both files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out [the import section](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/stubs.html) of type stub document, it should provide the answer for what you needed.

`__all__` is actually useful if you want to export private variables / types (prefixed with underscore). If you really don't like that, you can use the `import as` form:

```
from _foo import SomeType as SomeType
```

It guarantees `SomeType` to be re-exported.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I noticed this works:

foo.pyi:

```
from _foo import SomeType

__all__ = ["SomeType"]
```

I am not thrilled with this though, as it looks like it could have side effects, but for now it works.